# Safari and Touchpad specific issue causing animated element to get stuck

Tags: css, browser, safari

I have a very odd problem that I only observe with Safari, on a touchpad.

When scrolling down, my navbar fades in / down via CSS transition. If I happen to scroll back up, thus removing the class responsible for the transition, the navbar gets stuck visually in the wrong place, only on safari. The CSS / styles say the correct values, and even the hover/click handlers are in the right place.

That is, In the image below, my mouse is hovering at the blank white area, while the navbar stuck below gets highlighted.

There are several odd things about this:

- The element is the navbar via global styles, yet only happens on this particular page.
- I can't seem to trigger the problem via scrolling with the mouse.
- I can only trigger it via very subtle trackpad movements, or fast trackpad movements.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image]

Relevant CSS

```
.is-sticky-slide-down {
        @include experimental(animation, fadeInDown .3s ease-out 0s);
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to enabling `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` on elements. Removing this "fix" for hover glitches (like twitching opacity fades) fixed the other glitches on Safari.

To be clear, the fix is to **remove** `-webkit-backface-visibility` from affected elements.